# Why did I sum the wrong result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to have an advice for this `SUM` that doesn't work as expected.
I have to SUM data from the same day and display it in a table.
I did a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM giorni WHERE punto = '$punto' && STR_TO_DATE(giorno, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN   STR_TO_DATE('" . $d1 . "', '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('" . $d2 . "', '%d/%m/%Y') ORDER BY data";
```

This is the 'simple' one and it displays every single row, I have to put a SUM in it to make it show every day but `SUM` data from the same day.

These 2 rows must be shown as one:
[image]

Can anyone give me any help to create this query?

Comment: Have you tried group by?

Comment: Where's `SUM()`?

Comment: i did two: $sql2 = "SELECT *, 
SUM (a1, a2, a3, a4) 
FROM giorni 
GROUP BY giorni WHERE punto = '$punto' && STR_TO_DATE(giorno, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN   STR_TO_DATE('" . $d1 . "', '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('" . $d2 . "', '%d/%m/%Y') ORDER BY data";" maybe this two must be "joined" ?!

Comment: What's your expect result?You can't put multi parameter in `SUM` function

Comment: Going crazy with this query, i have to put one inside another?  Maathi with group byi can only see first row from a day -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand correctly you can try this.

You can't put multiparameter in `SUM` function.

When you use *Aggregate function* you need to add non-Aggregate columns in`GROUP BY` caluse.

```
 SELECT data,giorno,SUM(a1) as a1, SUM(a2) as a2, SUM(a3) as a3 , SUM(a4) as a4 
 FROM giorni 
 WHERE punto = '$punto' && STR_TO_DATE(giorno, '%d/%m/%Y') 
 BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('" . $d1 . "', '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('" . $d2 . "', '%d/%m/%Y') 
 GROUP BY data,giorno
 ORDER BY data";
```

Comment: D-Shih almost.. i have to sum every single row in a distinct variable. With this i have an undefined index with 

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
   
  
   
   echo '<tr>
     <td>'.$row['giorno'] . '</td>
     <td>'.$row['a1'].'</td>
     <td>'.$row['a2'].'</td>
     <td>'.$row['a3'].'</td>
     <td>'.$row['a4'].'</td>

Comment: D-Shih a sum of a single number is the number in itself :D You are right about the group by clause, but you just need 1 SUM function. SUM(p1+p2+p3); Otherwise nice answer!

Comment: @FrancescoElba If you want to  `sum` every single row you can see my edit answer. remember give a alias name after `sum` function, otherwise your PHP code `$row['a1']`  will not know `a1`.

Comment: @KamilG. I forget to remove it, thank for your remind.

Comment: That's the one! Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 3):

`SUM` is an aggregate function. It will calculate the total for each group. `+` is used for calculating two or more columns in a row.

Example:

```
ID  VALUE1  VALUE2
===================
 1   1       2
 1   2       2
 2   3       4
 2   4       5
```

So the following query:

```
SELECT  ID, VALUE1 + VALUE2
FROM    TableName
```

will result in:

```
ID, VALUE1 + VALUE2
1   3
1   4
2   7
2   9
```

However this query:

```
SELECT  ID, SUM(VALUE1 + VALUE2)
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY ID
```

Will result in:

```
ID, SUM(VALUE1 + VALUE2)
1   7
2   16
```

Comment: from the image i sent in the first post i have to expect as result

data              a1  a2  a3  a4

2018-07-04    13 14 125 5
2018-07-03    12  12  3  4

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT data,giorno,SUM(a1),SUM(a2),SUM(a3),SUM(a4)
FROM giorni
WHERE punto = '$punto' && STR_TO_DATE(giorno, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('" . $d1 . "', '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('" . $d2 . "', '%d/%m/%Y')
GROUP BY data
ORDER BY data
```

This code is assuming that you don't combine the four fields. Put `SUM` into the fields that you want to sum.

Comment: No results with this query